# Replacing ElementAt in a LINQ query to cover multiple elements

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to retrieve a list of Orders based on a multiple Location lists.

For context: a `Group` can have a multiple `Location`s (one-to-many) and an `Order` has one `Location` (many-to-one). I want to get all the Orders of a Group based on the `Location`s it has.

The following works for the first element in the list of `Group`s:

```
List<Order> orders = _context.Orders
    .Where(o => groups.ElementAt(0).Locations.Contains(o.Location))
    .ToList()
```

I want to change it such that it will not only check the first `Group` element, but all of them. Help is appreciated.

Comment: How is `groups` declared and initialized? Is it only a variable with the data in memory or is it another entity?

Comment: @Markus `groups` is an `ICollection<Group>` retrieved from the database from another unrelated entity

Comment: In that case there's no reason for the entire `groups.ElementAt(0).Locations` call to be inside the LINQ query, and every reason to pull it out. It looks like you're trying to generate a `Location IN (.....)` clause where the values come from `groups[0].Locations`. Store that in a variable outside the query and use it

Comment: If you want to match all locations use `var all=groups.SelectMany(g=>g.Locations);` to flatten the groups into a flat list of locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As groups is only a variable, you can use `SelectMany` to flatten the nested hierarchy before running the query:

```
var locations = groups.SelectMany(x => x.Locations).ToArray();
```

This basically changes a nested hierarchy

```
G1
  L11
  L12
G2
  L21
  L22
```

to a flat list of locations:

```
L11
L12
L21
L22
```

After that, you can use the locations in the query:

```
List<Order> orders = _context.Orders
  .Where(o => locations.Contains(o.Location))
  .ToList()
```

If the groups can contain duplicate locations, you could also add a `Distinct` after the `SelectMany`.

Comment: Is the `.ToArray()` there for performance reasons?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, so that the evaluation is only done once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this works as I intended :). @Robert Harvey Putting the `var locations`-part in-place throws an error as well, so it's not even possible for me

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var result = orders
    .Where(o => groups.All(f => 
        f.Locations.Contains(o.Location))).ToList();
```

Comment: I seriously doubt EF will be able to map this to what it really is, `o.Location IN (@loc1, @loc2,....)`